# Android - php mysql. no updated values

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

im new to android and php languages. I want to add point for students upon clicking a button in android. My database table is 'user' and my column that i want it to be updated is 'point'.

I tried to use this code for point.php that will be activate in onclick button in android.

```
 <?php 
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
 //Getting values 
 $point = $_POST['point_add'];

  $myVar = $point;
  var_dump($myVar); 
  $myVar= $myVar += 1; 
  var_dump($myVar);


 //importing database connection script 
 require "init.php";

 //Creating sql query 
 $sql = "UPDATE user SET point = '$point' WHERE id = $id;";

 //Updating database table 
 if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
 echo 'Data Updated Successfully';
 }else{
 echo 'Could Not Update Data Try Again';
 }

 //closing connection 
 mysqli_close($con);
 }

?>
```

this is my init.php

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);

$db_name = "mymerit";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_pass = "root";
$server_name = "localhost";

$con = mysqli_connect($server_name, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass, $db_name);

if(!$con){
    echo '{"message":"Unable to connect to the database."}';
}

?>
```

and this is my point.java in android

```
public class Point extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

String Err;
TextView err;
Button badd;
Context ctx=this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.point);
    badd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.point_add);
    err = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.err);
    Err = getIntent().getStringExtra("err");
    badd.setOnClickListener(this);
    err.setText(Err);
}

public void onClick(View v){
    BackGround b = new BackGround();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Thanks.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

class BackGround extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String point = params[0];
        String data="";
        int tmp;

        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.12/android/point.php");
            String urlParams = "point="+point;

            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            os.write(urlParams.getBytes());
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            InputStream is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            while((tmp=is.read())!=-1){
                data+= (char)tmp;
            }
            is.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

            return data;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Exception: "+e.getMessage();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Exception: "+e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        if(s.equals("")){
            s="Data saved successfully.";
        }
        Toast.makeText(ctx, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

}

There's no error and the android's working fine. but my point is not updated to 1. Is my code wrong somewhere?

Comment: i still can't manage to add point to the column point in my database even though i think i did my code correctly now..

Answer (score 0):

Is the point.php the actual file? Because there is a lot wrong there. You defined the variable $sql 3 times, first two don't have any effect on the code. I assume it's a snipped because you used variables that haven't been defined in the files, could you please clean up point.php? If this is actually the entire file try removing that error_reporting(0) and work your way through the errors.

Comment: dear P.Rempe. I think ive got the codes for point.php correct now. is this how i should write it? but i still cant figure out how to add 1 everytime the button is click.

Comment: $sql = "UPDATE user SET point = '$point' WHERE id = $id;"; You are "searching" for entries where id matches $id, that variable didnt get declared anywhere

Answer (score 0):

If i've understood properly, you want to add counter each click of button and push it into the database. So you could use sharedPref or simple do this, int counter =0,
OnClick of button counter += 1;
then you can push counter value in the database, Same you can try with string :)

Comment: hi, i wanted to change the string on id point_add in andorid as integer so that i could take them as an integer to be add into point column. ive updated the codes. is that how i should done it?